# Available Renderings Tabs are missing

Tags: sxa

We just upgraded our SXA from 1.7 to 1.8.1 and when we finished updating it, the add renderings window does not display the sections of the renderings.

I know this has been asked before, but it appears that it doesn't have an answer yet.

[image]

Comment: Did you run the content upgrade script from 170 to 181?   Go to `/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Upgrade/Current` and type `1700` in "Version". Then run the upgrade scripts it prompts you for.

Comment: @MarkCassidy just followed your procedure, the problem still persists. :(

Comment: Right. Well I wasn't sure - but it seemed worth a shot :-)

Answer (score 1):

I see such behaviour for the first time. I would check:

- if the production environment is properly set - *Add here* dialogue is taking renderings differently than a toolbox. There is a special script in SXA which is generating toolbox. Check if all the themes are properly moved to the production (especially `/sitecore/media library/Base Themes/Editing Theme`)
- check if for some reason (unknown or me) renderings in your production environment are not somehow placed under one item
- you showed Add here dialogue but I don't see the toolbox - all the renderings there are also under one section?

Few more things to mention. Toolbox sections depend on the parent item where the rendering is located:

[image]

Items under Available Renderings are just to group allowed renderings. To make managing of allowed renderings easier bu putting them into logical groups. E.g.: All Context renderings which are allowed are here:

[image]

Comment: There is no issue with the toolbox. all renderings are displaying properly but the problem is when click on "Add here" button, it showing all components without any category.

Comment: There may be issue in SXA installation. May be site not created property. Sometimes power shell will not create all required items. You can try creating another site.